# onSaveInstanceState Not writing data

Tags: android

My application has two Activity's.
I need an Activity to save a String, so for this I used the method below.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
  bundle.putString("ACTIVITY", "Dados que precisando ser salvos!");
  super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}
```

When I go to the second activity the above method is called, it is a correct behavior in the application.
But upon returning to my first activity, the bundle is null, and I'm not understanding why, can anyone help me?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (savedInstanceState != null){
   String teste = savedInstanceState.getString("ACTIVITY");
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that saved instance state works this way.  It isn't a semi-permanent cache for every activity.  You might have to use shared prefs here.

Comment: I would also suggest shared prefs, much more reliable than the saved bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` only when an activity is destroyed and recreated.

When an intent is called from say activity A to activity B, activity A is moved to back stack and not destroyed. Activity A `onStop()` is called and not `onDestory()`, so when you come back `onRestart()` is called and also the bundle doesn’t get saved.

Instead, you can use `sharedPreferences` in your activity A like this.

1.Save the value on click of button

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPref.edit().putString("ACTIVITY", "Dados que precisando ser salvos!").apply();
```

2.Restore the value from preferences on restring app

```
sharedPref.putString("ACTIVITY", null);
```

Edit:If your are not using activity use context to use preference

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Override

onRestoreInstanceState() where you want the values to be extracted :

```
@Override 
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState. 
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate. 
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("ACTIVITY");
}
```

Best practice to use both method in the same activity to restore and then use that data to some other activity, for that you can use shared preference or pass intent.

Comment: @Duk kindly accept the answer if that worked for you.

Comment: I tried to use the onRestoreInstanceState () method that you said, but it is not called when returning to the first activity.
What I find strange is that the first Activity should not be destroyed at the moment I'm going to the second activity of the app, because I'm not calling the finish ()

Comment: Where did you use this method onRestoreInstanceState in first activity or second activity ?

Comment: In my first Activity